# Overloading equals method in enum - any pitfalls?

Tags: java, enums

I have a Java enum that represents potential values for a given field, along with a unique identifier used to identify that value:

```
    public enum MyEnum {
       TYPEA("A"),
       TYPEB("B")

       private String code;

       private MyEnum(String code){
          this.code = code;
       }

       public String getCode(){
          return code;
       }
   }
```

Id like to add a custom comparator:

```
public boolean equals(String code){
    return getCode().equals(code);
}
```

This will allow me to compare my enums with strings.

Is there any pitfall that im missing? I cant see anything obviously wrong...

Comment: It seems fine - why would you need it though? Enums are constants, so it should be fine to just use a normal comparison to compare them.

Comment: What is the point? unless you initialise several enums with the same string of course...

Comment: Well, I interface with a lot of legacy code that uses plain old Strings, so this would simplify the migration while the legacy code catches up...

Comment: very bad. better give it another name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, two things:

- You're not overriding - you're overloading, and in a confusing way
- Your equality is not symmetric - `MyEnum.A.equals("A")` is true, but `"A".equals(MyEnum.A)` is false.

I wouldn't do it - where you *want* to perform equality checks with the code, it's easy to do so... but it's clearer to be explicit about it.

After all, it's only the difference between:

```
if (value.equals("A"))
```

and

```
if (value.getCode().equals("A"))
```

and I'd argue that the latter is clearer.

Comment: Or even `value.codeEquals("A")` if you really want the shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

The pitfall is quite simple: you didn't override `equals(Object)`, you introduced another method `equals(String)`. That method will not be used by any infrastructure invocations of `equals` against your object because dynamic dispatch applies to the runtime type of only the object on which the method is invoked and the *static* type of all method arguments is used to resolve the method signature at compile time.

If you "correct" this to `equals(Object)`, but keep the logic, then you have violated the `equals` contract because you don't satisfy the symmetry property: if another string is compared to your object via `String.equals(yourObject)` it will return false and you can't influence that. This is the limitation of using the single-dispatch mechanism of Java to define the equality relation.

Thankfully, enums already prevent you from attempting this by hardcoding `equals` and `hashCode` and making them final.